# Is there a setting in the APS viewer for 3D Annotations from Inventor to flip text direction on rotation as within Inventor?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-inventor

The below GIF is from the APS Viewer. You can see that the 3D annotations' text direction ***does not*** flip to allow readability from both sides.

[image]

The below GIF is from Inventor 2022. You can see that the 3D annotations' text direction flips to allow readability from both sides of the dimensions.

[image]

These use the same Inventor 2022 IPT file with 3D annotations. The APS viewer is pulling it from Fusion 360.

The initial 3D annotation display within the APS viewer seems to always face "forward". Changing the view cube "Home View" orientation or "Front View" orientation within the Inventor file before saving it & exporting it to Fusion 360 doesn't affect the annotation direction, just the view cube of the file within the viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no easy way to do that from the svf(2) itself.

What you see in the scene is actually static, so you would need to react to camera change events by translating and rotating the frags of the labels.
We have an extension to perform translations in elements in Viewer here, by the way. (refer to [transformation extension](https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-extensions/tree/main/public/extensions/TransformationExtension))

To handle this nicelly, I'd suggest you to add labels through an extension. You can refer to [Textgeometry blog](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/how-do-you-add-labels-forge-viewer).

We aso have a [Dimension Sample Extension](https://gist.github.com/JoaoMartins-callmeJohn/67d2ebb7699e304619bee08f86b0f62f) being developed that you can take advantage of to create dimensions in your scene.